# $\lim_{{n}\to{\infty}} (n+1)!(e-1-{1\over2}-...-{1\over n!})= ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How can I solve this problem: Find the limit of the following sequence:

$$\lim_{{n}\to{\infty}} (n+1)!(e-1-{1\over2}-...-{1\over n!})= ?$$

How to solve this using Cesaro-Stolz ? The numerator and denominator are decreasing, but do they decrease to zero ? I've tried to set $a_n$ as $e-1-{1\over2}-...-{1\over n!}$ and $b_n$ as $frac{1}{(n+1)!}$, and after using $\lim_{{n}\to{\infty}}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$ I get the result $\infty$, but in my text book it's 1.

Comment: Typo: replace `1` in `e-1-...` by `2`.

Comment: Is Cesaro-Stolz needed here ? The result is quite direct knowing that $a_n = \frac1{(n + 1)!}$ at leading order.

Comment: According to Cesar-Stolz, what you are computing is the limit of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{a_n}{(n+1)!}$. But this is not the result you want. You need to put $b_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$. But then $b_n$ is not divergent, so Cesaro-Stolz can't be used.

Comment: Sorry, so I did, I mistakenly copy-pasted the expression and forgot to put 1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since use Stolz 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(e-1-\dfrac{1}{2!}-\cdots-\dfrac{1}{n!})-(e-1-\dfrac{1}{2}-\cdots-\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}}{\dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}-\dfrac{1}{n!}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{-\dfrac{1}{n!}}{\dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}-\dfrac{1}{n!}}=1$$

Comment: This is invalid, because Cesaro-Stolz requires $b_n$ to be divergent.

Comment: There are other conditions for Cesaro-Stolz: 1) if limits of $a_n$ and  $b_n$ are zero, 2) if $b_n$ is strictly monotonous; 3) if $\lim_{{n}\to{\infty}}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$ exists.

Comment: @JohnG.: But then it's not the Cesaro-Stolz theorem any more (or even the Stolz-Cesaro theorem), as far as I can tell from a few internet searches.

Comment: I found this on the internet, and also in my math book, here was written Stolz-Cesaro1, and Stolz-Cesaro 2, and the second was what I mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

Put $a_n =e-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} , b_n =\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ then $$\frac{a_n -a_{n-1} }{b_n -b_{n-1}} =\frac{-\frac{1}{n!}}{\frac{1}{(n+1)!} -\frac{1}{n!}}\to 1$$